# Trace inequality for non-reversible Markov chain

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis, markov-chains, traces

Let $P \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ be the transition kernel for a Markov chain with stationary measure $\pi$ and define $P^\ast$ to be the time-reversed transition kernel defined by $P^\ast_{ij} := P_{ji} \pi_j/\pi_i$. Then I want to show that for any $k \ge 1$,
$$
\frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^{k} \mathrm{tr}(P^\ast P^i) \ge 1.
$$

I can prove this inequality for all $k \ge 1$ when the Markov chain is reversible (i.e. $P^\ast = P$). However, in the non-reversible case I can only prove it for $k=1,2$ and in the limit as $k \to \infty$. Is this inequality true for all $k \ge 1$ in the non-reversible case?

**Partial Progress:**

My partial progress begins by defining the symmetrized and centered transition matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ by $B_{ij} := \sqrt{\frac{\pi_i}{\pi_j}} P_{ij} - \sqrt{\pi_i \pi_j}$ which satisfies $\|B\|_{op} \le 1$. Then the above inequality reduces to:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k \mathrm{tr}(B^T B^i) \ge 0.
$$

In the reversible case, $B = B^T$, so the proof is very simple:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^k \mathrm{tr}(B^T B^i) = \sum_{i=1}^k \mathrm{tr}(B^{i+1}) = \sum_{j=1}^d \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_j(B)^{i+1} \ge 0
\end{align*}
because $|\lambda_i(B)| \le 1$ and $\min_{x \in [-1,1]}\sum_{i=1}^k x^{i+1} \ge 0$ for any $k$.

For the non-reversible case, $k=1$ is still trivial as it is equivalent to $\|B\|_F^2 \ge 0$. My proofs for $k=2$ and $k \to \infty$ decompose the trace as $\mathrm{tr}(B^T A_k B)$ where $A_k := \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} B^i$. Then it is sufficient to show that $v^T A_k v \ge 0$ for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^d$ (equivalently $A_k + A_k^T \succeq 0$). For $k=2$, this follows from:
$$
v^T A_2 v = v^T (I + B) v = \|v\|^2 + v^T B v \ge \|v\|^2 - \|v\|^2 = 0.
$$
and if $\|B\|_{op} < 1$ and $k \to \infty$, this follows from the Neumann series:
$$
v^T A_{\infty} v = v^T (I - B)^{-1} v = w^T (I-B) w \ge 0 \quad\text{where}\quad w := (I - B)^{-1} v.
$$
However, I'm not sure how to generalize this to general $k$. One can still write the partial sum as $A_k = (I - B)^{-1} (I - B^k)$. However, it's not clear to me whether $A_k + A_k^T \succeq 0$ for general $k$.

Also, in these proofs I managed to get away with just using that $\|B\|_{op} \le 1$. However, this is not sufficient in general. For example when $k = 5$ one can take
$$
B =
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\pi/3) & \sin(\pi/3) \\
-\sin(\pi/3) & \cos(\pi/3)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which satisfies $\|B\|_{op} = 1$. However, $\mathrm{tr}(B^T A_5 B) = -1 < 0$. The key is that this $B$ cannot arise from a Markov chain. For example, $\mathrm{tr}(B^3) = -2$ while $\mathrm{tr}(B^k) \ge -1$ for any $B$ which arises from a Markov chain, but I am not sure how to use this in the proof.

Comment: Is stationary measure $\mu$ or $\pi$?

Comment: Sorry, the stationary measure should be $\pi$. I just edited the original post to be consistent.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, just an observation: we can have $v^TA_kv < 0$.

Let $P$ be the $6\times 6$ permutation matrix describing a single cycle and $k = 5$. Specifically, let $P = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$. Then $A_5 = \frac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -2\\
-2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & -2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & -2 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & -2 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ and we have $v^T A_5 v = -2$ for $v = (0,-1,-1,0,1,1)^T$.

This doesn't produce a counterexample to the original problem. Generally, whenever $P$ describes a cyclic permutation of size $d$, we have $P^* = P^T = P^{-1}$ and $\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k \mathrm{tr}(P^*P^i) = \frac{d}{k}\left\lceil \frac{k}{d}\right\rceil \ge 1$, where $\lceil \cdot \rceil$ is the ceiling function. Note that we have equality whenever $k$ is a multiple of $d$. I ran some numerics which suggested that the inequality also holds in a small neighborhood around cyclic permutations.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'm posting more of a comment as an answer.  Not exactly sure if this could be very helpful or if you have thought about this.  But the case for $k\to\infty$ is quite easy to see (regardless of whether $P$ is reversible or not) if you think about the problem in the following way.

Consider the following Markov chain with the same state space as your original Markov chain.  The initial distribution is uniform over the $d$ states.  The transition matrix from time 0 to time 1 is $P^*$, and the transition matrix for later time steps is $P$.  Let this Markov chain be denoted as $(X(t):t=0,1,2,\dots)$.  Then what you want to show is equivalent to: for any $k\ge 1$,
$$\sum_{i=1}^dE\left[\frac{1}{k}\sum_{t=2}^{k+1}1_{\{X(t)=i\}}\middle|X(0)=i\right]\ge 1.$$
When $k\to\infty$, for each state $i$, the term inside the expectation is the time fraction that the Markov chain is in state $i$ (excluding time 0 and 1, which shouldn't matter in the long run), which should converge to $\pi_i$ (assuming aperiodicity and irreducibility).  So the sum over $i$ converges to $1$.

What you want to show is also equivalent to: for any $k\ge 1$,
$$\sum_{i=1}{d}E\left[\frac{1}{k}\sum_{t=2}^{k+1}1_{\{X(t)=X(0)\}}\right]\ge \frac{1}{d}.$$
It's unclear if this form is helpful or not.

Answer (score 0):

This seems generically true. Let's assume $P$ has a unique stationary distribution and let $Q$ be any other chain with $\pi$ as a stationary distribution (I don't think it is required that $Q$ have a unique stationary distribution). The example $P^*=D_{\pi}^{-1}P'D_{\pi}$ with $D_{\pi}=\text{diag}(\pi)$ does have $\pi$ as a unique stationary distribution.

Such $Q$ and $P$ commute with $1\pi'$ as well as $(I-1\pi')$. Set $\bar{P}=P-1\pi'$ and $\bar{Q}=Q-1\pi'$.

Then,
$$
\text{Tr}(QP^i) = 1 + \text{Tr}(\bar{Q}\bar{P}^i)$$
and
$$
T^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^T \text{Tr}(QP^i) = 1 + T^{-1}\text{Tr}\left(\bar{Q}\left(\sum_{i=1}^T \bar{P}^i\right) \right).
$$

The matrix $I-\bar{P}$ is invertible ($P$ has a single eigenvalue $\lambda_1= 1$ and the rest within $\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}: |\lambda| < 1 \}$), i.e. $|\lambda_i| < 1, \forall i \geq 2$. Hence,
$$
T^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^T \text{Tr}(QP^i) = 1 + T^{-1} \text{Tr}(\bar{Q}\bar{P}(I-\bar{P})^{-1}) + T^{-1}\text{Tr}(\bar{Q}\bar{P}(I-\bar{P})^{-1}\bar{P}^T).$$

The second term will decay geometrically in $T$ to 0 at rate given by spectral gap determined largest eigenvalue of $\bar{P}$: $\max \{|\lambda_i|: i \geq 2\}$. Hence, if we produce $\bar{Q}$ such that $\text{Tr}(\bar{Q}\bar{P}(I-\bar{P})^{-1}) < 0$ then we will have succeeded in establishing
$$
\limsup_T \left(T \left(T^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^T \text{Tr}(QP^{i})-1 \right)\right) = \text{Tr}(\bar{Q}\bar{P}(I-\bar{P})^{-1}) < 0
$$
i.e. the desired quantity will be roughly $1 + T^{-1}C$ with $C<0$.

For a generic Markov chain with unique stationary distribution, then the question is whether or not
$$
\text{Tr}(\bar{P}^*\bar{P}(I-\bar{P})^{-1}) \geq 0?
$$

Setting $P^{\alpha} = (1-\alpha) \cdot P + \alpha \cdot I$ for $\alpha \in [0,1]$ large enough seems to result in $\text{Tr}(\bar{P}^{\alpha,*}(I-\bar{P}^{\alpha})^{-1}) > 0$ or $\text{Tr}(\bar{P}^{\alpha,*}(I-\bar{P})^{-1})>0$.

### Time homogeneous case

If $Q=P$, then
$$
C = \text{Tr}(\bar{P}^2(I-\bar{P})^{-1}).
$$
Not clear that is non-negative in general. For reversible chains, this is clear as $\lambda^2/(1-\lambda) > 0$  for $\lambda \in (-1,1)$.

### Permutation example

The permutation example above is an example of a normal matrix, hence it is diagonalizable. We see then if $PP'=P'P$ then similarly $\bar{P}$ and $\bar{P}^*$ are normal and
$$
\text{Tr}(\bar{P}^*\bar{P}(I-\bar{P})^{-1}) = \sum_{i=2}^d \frac{|\lambda_i|^2}{1-\lambda_i}. 
$$
As all the real parts of $1-\lambda_i$ are non negative we see
$$
\text{Tr}(\bar{P}^*\bar{P}(I-\bar{P})^{-1}) \geq 0.
$$

### Probabilistic interpretation

Another way of expressing the diagonal
$$
M_T = \frac{1}{T} \sum_{i=1}^T\bar{P}^*\bar{P}^{i}
$$
is as follows. Let $X$ be a Markov chain that takes a single initial step from $P^*$ and all subsequent steps from $P$. We can write (up to a scaling depending only on $T$)
$$
M_T(s,s) = E^s[\widehat{\pi}_{T,2}(s)] - E^{\pi}[\widehat{\pi}_{T,2}(s)]
$$
using $E^s$ to denote the chain started from $s$ and $E^{\pi}$ started
from a draw from the stationary distribution. Above,
$$\widehat{\pi}_{T,2}(s) = 
\frac{1}{T} \sum_{i=2}^{T+1} \delta_s(X_i)
$$ is the empirical measure of the process up to time $T+1$ when we start counting from the 2nd step on. The diagonal entries will be non-negative for states $s$ if the chain started from $s$ spends more time on average at $s$ than if it had been started from the stationary distribution.

Comment: I see I started the sum at the wrong index, should be $P^i$ instead of $P^{i-1}$. This changes the answer even in the reversible case. Will correct...